# Asus q502l will not turn on

Tags: asus-laptop

I left it on while it was unplugged and it died, however the white light next to the light bulb symbol is continuously on and the light on the f2 key (that has the airplane symbol on it) is also continuously on when it is plugged on and unplugged.  I got this computer about 3 months ago and I turn it off regularly. I tried holding the power button for a whole minute and I have had it unplugged now. I am currently a student that heavily relies on my laptop to turn in and do assignments for college as well as my main source of entertainment and communication. I do not have the money to take it in somewhere, please help as soon as possible!

Comment: It must be under warranty, call ASUS

Comment: Unplug the charger, remove the battery, press and hold the power button for a good few seconds. Replace the battery, plug in the charger, let the laptop try and charge the battery for a few minutes (I'd say, about half an hour) and then try and power the laptop on. If this doesn't work then, as @pun has said, call ASUS for a warranty repair. Be warned, however, you'll need to send the device to them and there's no guarantee it will be returned with your data on. manufacturers often do a factory restore as part of the repair process to rule out any user error/fiddling.